# Laravel Pagination make data record displayed in duplicate

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel pagination to display set of records in 6 record per page format.The first page of last record data value displayed is same as the second page of first record data. The remains page show record data normally.

This sample report was displayed out with laravel pagination. The record was duplicate show out on row 6 and row 7.

```
No. Asset Id    Desc             Cost       Center Id  Requestor
1   CO-01-0001  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050001    David
2   CO-02-0002  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050001    David
3   CO-03-0003  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050001    Jack
4   CO-04-0004  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050002    Jack
5   C0-05-0005  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050002    Peter
6   C0-06-0006  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050003    Peter
```

< Page 1 >

```
No. Asset Id    Desc            Cost        Center Id   Requestor
7   C0-06-0006  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050003     Peter
8   CO-07-0007  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050004     David
9   CO-08-0008  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050005     Jack
10  CO-09-0009  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050006     Jack
11  C0-10-0010  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050007     Peter
12  C0-11-0011  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050008     Peter
```

< Page 2 >

I had try to display report without pagination. The duplicate problem didn't show out. This sample report was displayed out without laravel pagination. The record was displayed normally.

```
No. Asset Id    Desc            Cost        Center Id   Requestor
1   CO-01-0001  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050001     David
2   CO-02-0002  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050001     David
3   CO-03-0003  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050001     Jack
4   CO-04-0004  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050002     Jack
5   C0-05-0005  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050002     Peter
6   C0-06-0006  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050003     Peter
7   CO-07-0007  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050004     David
8   CO-08-0008  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050005     Jack
19  CO-09-0009  Lenovo M720     3,500.00    2050006     Jack
10  C0-10-0010  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050007     Peter
11  C0-11-0011  Lenovo M720     3,600.00    2050008     Peter
```

Below is my sample controller code:

```
$assets = DB::table('Asset_Tracking.dbo.fixedassets')
            ->leftjoin('Asset_Tracking.dbo.userassets', function ($join) {
                $join->on('fixedassets.assetid', '=', 'userassets.assetid')
                        ->where('userassets.active', 1); })
            ->leftjoin('company.dbo.staff', 'userassets.staff_id', '=', 'staff.id')
            ->select('fixedassets.*', 'userassets.desc', 'userassets.cost', 'userassets.centerid'
            , 'staff.name')
            ->whereIn('userassets.centerid', $costcentarr)->paginate(6);

        $rank = $assets->firstItem();

        return view('asset.show', ['rank' => $rank, 'assets' => $assets]);
```

Below is my sample blade code:

```
@foreach($assets as $asset)
<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-bordered"><tr>

<th><small>{{ $rank++ }}</small></th>
<th scope="row"><small>{{ $asset->assetid }}</small></th>
<td><small>{{ $asset->DESC }}</small></td>
<td><small>{{ $asset->COST }}</small></td>
<td><small>{{ $asset->centerid }}</small></td
<td><small>{{ $asset->name }}</small></td>

</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
{{ $assets->links() }}
```

i expect output 11 records, but the output is 12 records with 1 record was duplicated record on row 6 and row 7. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried reproducing the issue using the data provided but am unable to (asset 'C0-06-0006' is only shown once for me), so the code is probably fine.

Therefore my guess is there is something with the data. Please double check if everything has correct ID's, or if the tables contain duplicate records.

Unfortunately not enough info is provided to be certain. If this does not help, would you please provide a CREATE TABLE script and statements to fill the tables?

This is the SQL that Laravel generates for me for the second page. It may help locating the issue.

```
select fixedassets.*, userassets.desc, userassets.cost, userassets.centerid, staff.name 
from fixedassets 
left join userassets 
on fixedassets.assetid = userassets.assetid 
and userassets.active = 1 
left join staff on userassets.staff_id = staff.id 
where userassets.centerid in (2050001, 2050002, 2050003, 2050004, 2050005, 2050006, 2050007, 2050008) 
limit 6 offset 6
```

Comment: Hi JorisJ1. Thanks for your helping. May i know the way to find the SQL that Laravel generates for the second page? Thanks.

Comment: I use the [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). Another way would be to enable your database query logger.

Answer (score 0):

after i tried solve problem on these few days. finally found sound solution.
Just add ->orderBy('fixedassets.assetid ') on the sql. Everything work fine.